# Aonde tratar os dados em um projeto MVC

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando `Laravel` como exemplo.
No `Controller` eu faço 2 pesquisas.

```
public function index()
{
    $page_title = "Relatório";
    $projetos = Projetos::orderBy('alguma_coluna')->get();
    $subprojetos = Subprojetos::get();
    return view('pages.relatorio.index',
        compact('page_title','projetos ','subprojetos ')
    );
}
```

Eu preciso fazer um tratamento antes de imprimir esses dados na `View`.

*O código abaixo é apenas um exemplo de tratativa dos dados*

```
foreach($projetos AS $thisRow) {
    $isDuplicate = false;
    $projeto_nome =  $thisRow["projeto_nome"];
    $hasNewIcon = $thisRow["hasNewIcon"];
    $img_src = $thisRow["img_src"];

    if($hasNewIcon === "1"){
        $hasNewIcon = "<img src='algumaimg.jpg'>";
    } else {
        $hasNewIcon = "";
    }
    foreach ($subprojetos AS $r) {
        $subprojeto_nome = $r["subprojeto_nome"];
        if($contador > 0){
             $isDuplicate = true;
        }
        $contador++;
    }
    $html .= <<<HTML
                     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6 thumb">
                            <img src="{$img_src}" class="img-responsive"/>
                            <div class="equal-height-panels">
                                <div class="row">
                                  <h5 class="text-center">{$projeto_nome}</h5>
                                    {$hasNewIcon}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
HTML;
}
```

A minha pergunta é: Eu devo fazer esse tratamento aonde? No `Controller`, na `View` ou no `Model`?

Comment: Seria interessante você fazer qualquer tratamento no Model. E todas estas partes envolvendo HTML você deve colocar direto na View e fazer as condicionais lá, usando a sintaxe do Blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma classe responsável por representar seus modelos para qualquer tipo de saída, isso inclui html, json e xml. Existe um pattern de estrutura de projeto normalmente utilizado em Ruby chamado de [MVP (Model-View-Presenter)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter).

Felizmente já existe uma [library](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) no Github que faz isso para você, e, foi especialmente desenvolvido para o Laravel pelo Jeffrey Way, não sei se você sabe mas é quem escreve e grava as aulas do [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/).

Essa library lhe permite criar classes responsáveis por representar um modelo seu para a view. Seu código fica mais ou menos dessa forma:

#### Presenter

```
<?php
namespace App\Presenters;

use Laracasts\Presenter\Presenter;

class UserPresenter extends Presenter {

    public function fullName()
    {
        return $this->first . ' ' . $this->last;
    }
}
```

#### Modelo

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laracasts\Presenter\PresentableTrait;

class User extends Model {

    use PresentableTrait;

    protected $presenter = 'UserPresenter';
}
```

#### View

```
<h1>Olá, {{ $user->present()->fullName }}</h1>
```

Isso trás muitas melhorias para o seu código, principalmente quando você precisar mudar a lógica de apresentação do seu modelo.

- Remove código duplicado.
- Diminui as linhas de códigos dentro do seu HTML, no máximo uma chamada para uma função.
- Se você precisar modificar a forma que estes dados são enviados para a sua view, basta modificar o método dentro da classe presenter que o sistema inteiro acompanha esta mudança.
- Você pode aplicar testes na sua classe responsável por apresentar o seu modelo, evitando a quebra de código.

Uma dica extra, se um dia você se deparar com muito código responsável por construir queries dentro do seu controller, você pode fugir para o [Repository Pattern](http://shawnmc.cool/the-repository-pattern).